# about the error of file.exists in R (returns false)

Tags: r

Why is it that file.exists() returns false?

```
setwd("~/Desktop/demo")
dir <- "~/Desktop/demo"

samp <- iris
write.csv(samp,"samp.csv")
samp<-read.csv("samp.csv")

file <- file.path(dir,"tem", iris$Sepal.Length, "df.sf.gz")
file #

 file.exists(file)
```

This should be TRUE. 
But mine is FALSE

Comment: file.exists() return TRUE or FALSE, whats is your propouse, its not clear.

Comment: I mean this should be TRUE, right??

Comment: why should it be TRUE??

Comment: I get it now, so, you did not create a fisic file in your hard drive, you just created inside R, só this could not evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

understant that `dir` storre the path

```
file.exists(dir)
TRUE
```

But `dir` is refearing to a file that exist, so `TRUE`.

`file.exists(file)` its not a real file in you HD just in R( or hold anything that evaluates to `TRUE`), so `FALSE`.

**TIP:**
Recursive file creation, messing arround and you can get what you want i think.

```
dir.create(file.path('testdir2', 'testdir3'), recursive = TRUE)
```